# Can you use bitwise operators with enum classes without casting?

Tags: c++, enum-class

I like to use enum classes, but I use them as flags sometimes and I have to constantly cast to `int` if I want to use a bitwise operator. Is there a way to do this without casting? I don't think you can define the operators for them?

If I have functions that take an enum class, do I have to do this?

```
enum class Flags { FLAG1, FLAG2, FLAG3};

void setFlags(Flags flags){}

int main()
{
      setFlags((Flags)((int)Flags::FLAG1 | (int)Flags::FLAG2 | (int)Flags::FLAG3));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overload |= operator on scoped enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889414/how-to-overload-operator-on-scoped-enum)

Comment: If you want the enum to implicitly convert to int, remove the `class`.

Comment: But then that allows for mistakes in passing to functions right? I just have to be extra careful?

Comment: What do you mean "allows for mistakes in passing to functions"?

Comment: I thought only with "class" is it strongly typed, otherwise you can pass other types to functions that take that enum.

Comment: It is indeed strongly typed with "class".

Answer (score 5):

The `class` after the `enum` specifies that an enumeration is strongly typed and that its enumerators are scoped. Beware, `enum class` has only assignment, initialization and comparisons defined by default. Nevertheless, an enumeration is user-defined type, as such, you can define operators for it.

---

If you don't want to explicitly qualify enumerator names and want enumerator values to be `ints` (without the need for an explicit conversion), you can remove the `class` from `enum class` to get "plain" `enum`. Enumerators are exported to the surrounding scope to evade name collisions, you can wrap with namespace.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Flags {
    enum : int 
    {
        bit_1 = 0x1,
        bit_2 = 0x2
    };
}

int main()
{
    int num = 11;
    if (num & Flags::bit_1)
        std::cout << "lsb is on!\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "lsb is off!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

**References**:

- A Tour of C++ Second edition by Bjarne Stroustrup

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to overload operators on scoped enums yourself, why not using one of libraries that do that for you.

For example:

- [enum-flags](https://github.com/grisumbras/enum-flags)
- [magic-enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum)

I have created such library myself - [bitflags](https://github.com/m-peko/bitflags) (it's not the best but does what I want) where you can create your flags by just specifying the following:

```cpp
BEGIN_BITFLAGS(Flags)
    FLAG(none)
    FLAG(flag_a)
    FLAG(flag_b)
    FLAG(flag_c)
END_BITFLAGS(Flags)
```

and then you can do:

```cpp
int main() {
    Flags flags = Flags::flag_a | Flags::flag_b;

    if (flags & Flags::flag_a) {
        std::cout << "flag_a is set" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "flag_a is not set" << std::endl;
    }

    flags.toggle(Flags::flag_a);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that you don't need to specify the type for your flags because the minimum size type is being used automatically, and, furthermore, you don't need to specify values of your flags. They are assigned automatically too.