# c++: OR operator: "enum" vs "enum class"?

Tags: c++

Unscoped enumeration WORKS with the OR operator where the scoped one does not... WHY and how to work with it?

The enum type type-name is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3)

```
#include <iostream>

enum  eDogType
{
  eHusk = 0,
  eGold,
  eAus,
  eGerm,
  ePud
};


int main()
{
  eDogType eDog1 = eDogType::eAus;
  eDogType eDog2 = eDogType::eGerm;
  
  eDogType eDog = static_cast<eDogType>(eDog1 | eDog2);  // WORKS


  std::cout << "Hello World: " << eDog << "\n";

  return(0);
}
```

---

Scoped enumeration fails in the OR operator

```
#include <iostream>

enum class eDogType
{
  eHusk = 0,
  eGold,
  eAus,
  eGerm,
  ePud
};


int main()
{
  eDogType eDog1 = eDogType::eAus;
  eDogType eDog2 = eDogType::eGerm;
  
  eDogType eDog = static_cast<eDogType>(eDog1 | eDog2); // FAILS: C++ no operator matches these operands


  std::cout << "Hello World: " << eDog << "\n";

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question?

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: I'd vote to close for duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64494432/3185968 , but I've already voted to close for unclear because there was no question here originally. Maybe others can now vote to close for dupe?

Comment: I suggest to use a `template operator |` function, that highly simplifies ORing of _any_ `enum` type: `template<class T> [[nodiscard]] constexpr inline T operator| (T v1, T v2) { typedef typename std::underlying_type_t<T> type; return T((type)v1 | (type)v2); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enum eDogType` values are processed as `int` values, where `enum class eDogType` values are not (they are processed as values of type `eDogType`).

So in the first case, the `operator | (int, int)` is used, whereas in the second case, the `operator | (eDogType, eDogType)` is needed (but not found).

---

```
#include <iostream>

enum class  eDogType
{
  eHusk = 0,
  eGold,
  eAus,
  eGerm,
  ePud
};


int main()
{
  eDogType eDog1 = eDogType::eAus;
  eDogType eDog2 = eDogType::eGerm;
  
  eDogType eDog = static_cast<eDogType>(static_cast<int>(eDog1) | static_cast<int>(eDog2));


  std::cout << "Hello World: " << static_cast<int>(eDog) << "\n";

  return(0); 
}
```

Comment: more work to scope the enum into a class...

Comment: it really depends on your needs; besides, take care : if you want to use something like `ePug | eGerm`, enum values must be 1, 2, 4, 8 ... so that the binay OR behaves as expected